# Unable to read from Settings file

Tags: c#, application-settings, settings.settings

I created a console application and added a Settings1.settings file through the Add -> New Item -> Settings file. When I try to access Properties.Settings intellisense is not recognising Properties.

But when I try to add a settings file through Properties -> Settings -> Create settings file, Properties is shown by intellisense..

Also, manually created settings file appears in my Solution Explorer, but the one created through Properties -> Settings -> Create settings file appear in a separate path "Properties -> Settings".

What is the difference between both ???

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Right-click the file, and examine its build properties. The difference is bound to be there :)

Comment: I cannot find any difference. .Both have the same proprties :(

Answer (score 1):

Settings lives under the Properties namespace as child hence you get the intellisense working correctly

In Settings you can create type variables for scope such as user or application

A huge example will be that I can save my applications settings in one the variables

Comment: Thanks HatSoft :) But what if I want to access the values of settings file that are added not in Properties folder ?? Is the only way to access them is through configurationManager.appsettings ( assuming that I gave all the values as application scoped ) ??